# How to save PictureBox Image to SQL in VB.NET ( Windows Form )

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I need to save a form in it user browse image & set it to a  PictureBox But on another button I need save that image to SQL Server .I have a stored procedure with Insert Command (with Image Datatype)

**Browser Image from Desktop, PictureBox Code** :-

```
   Public Sub SelectImage()

        With OpenFileDialog1
            '.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
            .Filter = "All Files|*.*|Bitmaps|*.bmp|GIFs|*.gif|JPEGs|*.jpg"
            .FilterIndex = 4
        End With

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D

        End If
    End Sub
```

**Save Button Code**

```
Public Sub Insert_Update_Personal()
        Dim UploadImage As Bitmap = PictureBox1.Image

        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("sp_Insert_Update_Personal", con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@childrenage", TextBox10.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", UploadImage)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hrcomments", TextBox5.Text)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

**But When I run the form it gives me error  "No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type."**

Comment: You'll need to convert the image to a byte array before pushing it into the database.

Comment: Also, do it from the original image, not from the PictureBox.

Answer (score 1):

try this: (***Change MySqlConnection to SQLConnection because i'm using MySQL in my example***)

```
    Public Shared Function ByteToImage(ByVal blob() As Byte) As Bitmap
        Dim mStream As New MemoryStream
        Dim pData() As Byte = DirectCast(blob, Byte())
        mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length))
        Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(mStream, False)
        mStream.Dispose()
        Return bm
    End Function
```

then use it like this:

```
Private Function InsertImage(ByVal ImagePath As String, ByVal oIDNum As String) As Boolean
    Dim iPhoto() As Byte = jwImage.FileImageToByte(ImagePath)
    Dim xBool As Boolean = False
    Using xConn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionClass.ConnectionString)
        Try
            Dim xComm As New MySqlCommand
            With xComm
                .CommandText = "InsertImage"
                .Connection = xConn
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                .Parameters.AddWithValue("xID", oIDNum)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("xImage", iPhoto)
            End With

            xConn.Open()
            xComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            xComm.Dispose()
            xBool = True
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MySQL Error: " & ex.Number, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            xBool = False
        End Try
    End Using

    Return xBool
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Thanks Just want to know  what is "jwImage" is it a PictureBox ID?

Comment: Can you please explain this line   Dim iPhoto() As Byte = jwImage.FileImageToByte(ImagePath)

Also when I  will call this function  "ByteToImage"

Comment: @Pankaj jwImage is a name of a class. `FileImageToByte` as the name says, it converts an Image into Byte Array.